# C# equivalent of Obj-C's NSCharacterSet? Need help converting iOS code

Tags: c#, .net

Here is my code in Objective-C for iOS that I need help converting to C#:

```
NSString kLegal = @"0123456789(['!";
NSString character = @"(";
NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:kLegal] invertedSet];
NSString *filtered = [[character componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

I'm familiar with C# and .NET but really don't have a clue where to begin here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Objective-C or iOS, but from Googling around it seems that `NSCharacterSet` is used to filter characters - either specifying the characters you want or those you don't want.

You can do that in C# in several ways. Here's one:

```
string filter="0123456789(['!";
string text="My phone number is (121)5551234!";
```

If you want to see only the characters in filter, you do this:

```
string filtered = new string(text.Where(c=>filter.IndexOf(c)>=0).ToArray());
```

If you want to see only the characters not in the filter, you can do this:

```
string filtered = new string(text.Where(c=>filter.IndexOf(c)<0).ToArray());
```

Both aren't the most efficient way to do this. If you want efficiency, use a regular expression.